# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'play'

Tags: python, discord.py

Here is code of discord music bot

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('ready')


def search(query):
    with YoutubeDL({'format': 'bestaudio', 'noplaylist':'True'}) as ydl:
        try: requests.get(arg)
        except: info = ydl.extract_info(f"ytsearch:{arg}", download=False)['entries'][0]
        else: info = ydl.extract_info(arg, download=False)
    return (info, info['formats'][0]['url'])


async def join(ctx, voice):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel

    if voice and voice.is_connected():
        await voice.move_to(channel)
    else:
        voice = await channel.connect()


@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def play(ctx, *, query):
    FFMPEG_OPTS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}

    video, source = search(query)
    voice = get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    await join(ctx, voice)
    await ctx.send('Music is playing')

    voice.play(FFmpegPCMAudio(source, **FFMPEG_OPTS), after=lambda e: print('done', e))
    voice.is_playing()


client.run(token)
```

And here is the error

Ignoring exception in command play:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Aboba\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "D:/Aboba/bommmm.py", line 50, in play
voice.play(FFmpegPCMAudio(source, **FFMPEG_OPTS), after=lambda e: print('done', e))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'play'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Comment: The stack trace shows you which line the error occurred on (line 50), and the error description is telling you that the value of voice was None when the line executed. Presumably the line beginning **voice = get(** a few lines above failed.